# Change Log-Subsystem on JBoss 7

Tags: java, logging, jboss

We would like to use logback as slf4j-backend on a webapp which is deployed in JBoss. To do so, I first tried to exclude the jboss-logging-module dependencies from the project and ship the webapp with the logback-libraries. This sort of works, yet it has the disadvantage that logging of the server itself and logging of the webapp have to be configured in different places (and logs are written in different places).

Is it possible to completely get rid of the jboss-slf4j implementation and provide your favourite one instead?